# Android Beacon transmitter stops automatically why?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am developing an Android application which has functionality to interact with ibeacons and also to act as ibeacon using altbeacon android beacon library ( https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html ).

I have got success in beacon detection and advertisement but my app suddenly stops beacon advertising and  didRangeBeaconsInRegion() event stop detecting beacons nearby unless I stopped the bluetooth and restart the bluetooth again.

Please let me know, how I can correct my problem, and also any good guideline for working with beacons in android will great.

I am using Moto X 2gen 5.1.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a crash in the bluetooth stack on the device.  Can you try to reproduce this while capturing a full LogCat excerpt including system messages?  If you can capture this and link to it, it would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi dear, Thank you for your response here is the complete log.

Comment: Dear, I have also noticed that, on Samsung S5 it is not happening too much. I need a solution to work on all android devies higher than lolipop.